# WSO2 ESB Axis2 Service throwing Host name verification failed for host

Tags: ssl, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I have created an AXIS service which connects to WSO2 Identity Server and validates a token.
When I deploy this axis service on WSO2 App Server, I get the correct response.
Where as when I deploy it on WSO2 ESB, I get the following error

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:93)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:68)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:346)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.stub.OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub.validate(OAuth2TokenValidationServiceStub.java:184)
at com.xxx4.yyy.security.token.service.TokenValidationService.validateToken(TokenValidationService.java:67)
at com.xxx4.yyy.security.token.facade.TokenValidationFacade.validateToken(TokenValidationFacade.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

[2013-10-03 14:42:56,160] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : 172.20.5.110
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : 172.20.5.110
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:285)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:372)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the parameter `HostnameVerifier` to `AllowAll` for transportSender in the Axis2 configuration (axis2.xml).

```
<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
   <!--...-->
   <!--supports Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost or the default if none specified -->
   <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
   <!--supports Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost or the default if none specified -->
</transportSender>
```

Comment: Thank you, it resolved that issue.  However, I am getting a different error now - ERROR - AxisEngine Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation.  However it is working 100% fine on AS - Any thoughts in this regard, please!

Comment: The following is the error I am gettingERROR - AxisEngine Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: {http://oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org}validate
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Message Receiver not found for AxisOperation: {http://oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org}validate

Comment: When I change the transportSender from ESB default one to AS default for https - It is working as expected.  I am not sure if that is correct approach or not, please suggest!

Comment: Found the solution for the above problem, when we try add Axis2 service using WSO2 Dev Stud, it adds messageReceivers and add receivers for In and InOut operations.  When I remove these message receivers from the service definition, I do not see the errors as reported.

Comment: This to me is not a viable solution,in a production environment, as it creates a security flaw/ hole.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ratha's answer, the following official documentation provides a detailed explanation about hostname verification in WSO2 products.

[Enabling HostName Verification](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Enabling+HostName+Verification)