# WSO2 AM Host name verification failed for host

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am new to the WSO2 AM, so I am not sure if this is the right place for my question.
Nevertheless. . .  I have recently installed WSO2 AM and published a new API.

At first, everything worked as expected (I deploy the API using "localhost" as the hostname for the wso2am)

Then, I change the hostname used by the product following the instructions detailed here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Changing+the+Hostname
Now I am able to access the wso2am using the new hostname but I'm not able to use the published API because I get the following error:

`2019-09-06 15:16:18,674 [-] [HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1] ERROR TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : localhost javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : localhost`

I have followed these instructions ([WSO2 ESB Axis2 Service throwing Host name verification failed for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155521/wso2-esb-axis2-service-throwing-host-name-verification-failed-for-host)) to disable the hostname verification and then, the API worked again (I changed the parameter "HostnameVerifier" to “AllowAll” on the axis2.xml configuration file)

However, the security guidelines for deploying a WSO2 product in a production environment said I should enable HostName Verification.

Is there another configuration that I am missing for this to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when the server URL is not aligned with its certificate. In a standalone APIM pack, the default keystore has the certificate CN as 'localhost'. In order to use ur HOSTNAME as the hostname you would have to create a new keystore with the new hostname as mentioned in [WSO2 Admin guide / Creating New Keystores](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores). Also the new hostname should be added to /etc/hosts. Could you try this and check.

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment, the recommended approach is to enable hostname verification and use a proper certificate for the hostnames. WSO2's default Keystore contains the self-signed certificate and for production, it is recommended to change the Keystore. Please go through these security guidelines which not only talks about Keystores but some other important stuff. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Security+Guidelines+for+Production+Deployment